# Не запускается сайт на spring (There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Люди добрые помогите разобраться что я делаю не так у себя в коде, почему у меня на локалхосте не поднимается сайт пишет мне (This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).)
Вот мой application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/user_db
spring.datasource.username=mysql
spring.datasource.password=mysql
```

Вот мой класс модели

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "surname")
  private String surname;
  @Column(name = "age")
  private int age;
  @Column(name = "course")
  private int course;
```

}

Вот интерфейс репозитория

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
```

}

Вот мой класс Сервис

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
  @Autowired
  public  StudentRepository repository;

  public Student findById(Long id){
    return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
  }

  public List<Student> findAll(){
   return repository.findAll();
  }

  public Student saveStudent(Student student){
    return repository.save(student);
  }

  public void deleteStudent(Long id){
    repository.deleteById(id);
  }

  }
```

Вот мой контроллер

```
 @Controller
 public class StudentController {
  @Autowired
  public StudentService studentService;


  @GetMapping("/students")
  public String findAll(Model model){
    List<Student> allStudent = studentService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("students", allStudent);
    return "student-list";
  }

  @GetMapping("/student-create")
  public String createStudentForm(Student student){
    return "student-create";
  }

  @PostMapping
  public String createStudent(Student student){
    studentService.saveStudent(student);
    return "redirect:/students";
  }
}
```

И вот мой html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Student-List</title>

</head>
<body>
<div th:switch="${students}">
  <h2 th:case="null">Студентов не найдено!</h2>
  <div th:case="*">
    <h2>Студенты</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Фамилия</th>
            <th>Возраст</th>
            <th>Курс</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="student : ${students}">
            <td th:text="${student.id}"> </td>
            <td th:text="${student.name}"> </td>
            <td th:text="${student.sername}"> </td>
            <td th:text="${student.age}"> </td>
            <td th:text="${student.course}"> </td>
            <td th:href="@{student-update/{id}(id=${student.id})}">Редактировать </td>
            <td th:href="@{student-delete/{id}(id=${student.id})}">Удалить </td>
        </tr>
        ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p><a href="/student-create">Добавить нового пользователя</a></p>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

В базе через phpmyadmin создал бд user_db и там таблицу students и там уже добавил пару студентов что бы хоть что-то вывелось.

Вот что в логах вывело

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)

2021-04-22 10:23:27.785  INFO 4528 --- [           main] c.e.studentlist.StudentlistApplication   : 
Starting StudentlistApplication using Java 1.8.0_201 on DESKTOP-7BUHOLO with PID 4528 
(C:\projectIdea\studentlist\target\classes started by Denis in C:\projectIdea\studentlist)
2021-04-22 10:23:27.789  INFO 4528 --- [           main] c.e.studentlist.StudentlistApplication   : 
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-22 10:23:29.207  INFO 4528 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : 
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-22 10:23:29.297  INFO 4528 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : 
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 71 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-22 10:23:29.947  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : 
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-22 10:23:29.957  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : 
Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-22 10:23:29.957  INFO 4528 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : 
Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-04-22 10:23:30.105  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : 
Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-22 10:23:30.105  INFO 4528 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2233 ms
2021-04-22 10:23:30.365  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : 
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-22 10:23:30.418  INFO 4528 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : 
HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-04-22 10:23:30.533  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : 
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-22 10:23:30.630  INFO 4528 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : 
HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-22 10:23:30.880  INFO 4528 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : 
HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-22 10:23:30.897  INFO 4528 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : 
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2021-04-22 10:23:31.859  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : 
HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-22 10:23:31.868  INFO 4528 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : 
Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-22 10:23:32.172  WARN 4528 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : 
spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during 
view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-22 10:23:32.321  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : 
Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-22 10:23:32.594  INFO 4528 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : 
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-22 10:23:32.604  INFO 4528 --- [           main] c.e.studentlist.StudentlistApplication   : 
Started StudentlistApplication in 5.643 seconds (JVM running for 6.948)
2021-04-22 10:23:52.616  INFO 4528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : 
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-22 10:23:52.616  INFO 4528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : 
Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-22 10:23:52.618  INFO 4528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : 
Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-04-22 10:23:52.635  WARN 4528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not 
supported]
2021-04-22 10:23:54.655  WARN 4528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : 
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not 
supported]
```

Comment: В какой момент это происходит? По какому url делаете запрос?

Comment: сразу когда прописываю http://localhost:8080

Comment: покажите настройки security. Там, вроде, надо явно разрешить разные типы запросов.

Comment: дело в том что в моем проекте нет spring security.Я до него еще не дошел в изучении. Или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка возникает, потому что ваш контроллер `StudentController` имеет дефолтный маппинг.
Это значит, что любые запросы по адресу `localhost:8080` будут резолвиться именно на него.

Далее рассмотрим маппинг ваших методов:

```
@GetMapping("/students")  //доступен по GET localhost:8080/students
public String findAll(Model model)

@GetMapping("/student-create")  // доступен по GET localhost:8080/student-create
public String createStudentForm(Student student)

@PostMapping // тоже дефолтный маппинг, доступен по POST localhost:8080
public String createStudent(Student student)
```

Вот в последнем методе и кроется ошибка, которую вы получаете в логах:
`[org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not  supported]`

Когда вы переходите на `localhost:8080`, то у вас резолвится для выполнения метод `createStudent`, а он помечен аннотацией `@POST`

На вашем месте я бы переписал маппинг контроллеров и методов следующим образом:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/student")
public class StudentController

@GetMapping  //доступен по GET localhost:8080/student
public String findAll(Model model)

@GetMapping("/student-create")  // доступен по GET localhost:8080/student/student-create (не знаю правда, зачем вам этот метод)
public String createStudentForm(Student student)

@PostMapping // доступен по POST localhost:8080/student
public String createStudent(Student student)
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое за ответ. Сделал как вы сказали, но в таком случае появляется другая ошибка (There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).)

Comment: А что вы используете на фронте? Thymeleaf?

Comment: Верно,его Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем котроллере нужно указать метод с аннотацией @GetMapping(value = "/")

Например:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String helloPage(Model model){
List<Student> allStudent = studentService.findAll();
model.addAttribute("students", allStudent);
return "student-list";}
```